# Overcoming the reserved word "IN" in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just for reference I am using SQL Azure.

I noticed when I am trying to select data from a table based on a license plate and the state of that plate I get no results back if the state is "IN". I realize the word "IN" is reserved in SQL server; however, I am containing that within quotes in my query. I currently am in testing phase and have only one record in the table which has a lisence plate 287YGB and state IN.

If I write my query as follows I get nothing back.

```
SELECT MakeModel, CitizenID, VehicleID FROM tblVehicles WHERE tblVehicles.Lisence = '287YGB'  AND tblVehicles.PlateState = 'IN'
```

If I write my query this way I get back my result. But this is not good enough.

```
SELECT MakeModel, CitizenID, VehicleID FROM tblVehicles WHERE tblVehicles.Lisence = '287YGB'
```

And finally, if I write my query this way I get the only row in the table.

```
SELECT MakeModel, CitizenID, VehicleID FROM tblVehicles
```

From these tests I can see that the last where parameter is causing the problem. I am assuming it is due to the fact that the word "IN" is reserved. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sure the data doesn't have some leading space or surrounding other non visible characters? There is no problem with searching for `'IN'`

Comment: If contained in quotes - you should not be having this problem...

Comment: `IN` is a reserved keyword.  `'IN'` is a String.  If you have ticks around the value it is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: That's a coincidence. If your top query works, your second query should work, too, and so should the third one.

Comment: try your first query with `LIKE '%IN%'` instead of `='IN'` to see if you don't have spaces problems.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus your suggestion worked but I am still confused. I thought about the issue of leading or trailing spaces etc and went into the actual table to check. There are no spaces or anything, just the two letters "IN"

Comment: What does `SELECT CAST(tblVehicles.PlateState AS VARBINARY(10))  FROM tblVehicles ` return?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I do not. This is not a stored procedure at the moment. I am just writing it directly into the query interface in azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reserved words usually only cause problems if you're using them as field names, and in that case you need to wrap them with brackets ("[]") to eliminate the problem.  I will amost guarantee you that your PlateState has some garbage in it, so you need to either trim it first (LTRIM(RTRIM(PlateState)) = 'IN') or use Like '%IN%' instead, and this will return the results you expect.

Comment: It seems you're right. My state columns nvarchar limit was set at 50. I don't like restricting it lower than that, chalk it up to OCD, so I decided to try and restricting it to two characters. Once I did that my original query worked. Now I am wondering just what garbage was in there and where did it get introduced. I strictly typed in 'IN' when I saved my vehicle and followed the PlateState variable in my program. The string always read "IN". Hate these little quirks

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO "My state columns nvarchar limit was set at 50. I don't like restricting it lower than that, chalk it up to OCD, so I decided to try and restricting it to two characters."

Comment: @Adrian "So even when you know your state acronym will be 2 characters, you insist on a variable length up to 50 characters?"

Comment: http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/31000000/Come-at-me-bro-rainbow-dash-31030597-500-310.gif

Comment: @Adrian I take deep offense to being called "bro." You're basically saying, I want to waste space because I'm OCD. [You could be saving 2 bytes per row, but you're OCD.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT MakeModel, CitizenID, VehicleID FROM tblVehicles WHERE tblVehicles.Lisence = '287YGB'  AND LTRIM(RTRIM(tblVehicles.PlateState)) = 'IN'
```